# transforming xml to table format with xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I don't quite understand how to get an example seen below to transform into a table format seen below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="sample.xsl"?>
<Form name="Sample Form">
<Prop title="Name">
<PropList type="list">
<Item value="Joe"></Item>
<Item value="Anna"></Item>
<Item value="Mark"></Item></PropList></Prop>
<Prop title="ID">
<PropList type="list">
<Item value="123"></Item>
<Item value="789"></Item>
<Item value="345"></Item></PropList></Prop>
<Prop title="Code">
<PropList type="list">
<Item value="WFUO"></Item>
<Item value="SOP"></Item>
<Item value="ASAP"></Item></PropList></Prop></Form>
```

wanted output: sorry I'm unable to post an image

```
Joe  123 WFUO
Anna 789 SOP
Mark 345 ASAP
```

I am only able to get it to output all values to one row or one row. Please let me know if you can help.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head><title>Sample Form</title></head>
            <body>
                <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Code</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates select='Form/Prop/PropList/Item'/>
            </table>
            </body></html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Prop">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@value"/></td>
            <xsl:apply-templates select='Form/Prop/PropList/Item'/>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Item">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@value"/></td>
            <xsl:apply-templates select='Form/Prop/PropList/Item'/>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

New updated code with some help from fellow members:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:key name="PropKey" match="Prop" use="@title" />

  <xsl:template match="Form">
         <html>
            <head><title>Sample Form</title></head>
            <body>
                <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Code</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates select='Prop'/>
            </table>
            </body></html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Prop">
    <xsl:variable name="thisGroup" select="key('PropKey', @title)">   </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$thisGroup"/> 
    <xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id($thisGroup[1])">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="PropList"/>  
    </xsl:if> 

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PropList">
     <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="Item/@value"/>
     </td>           
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: This is not the main issue here, but you should know that `<xsl:apply-templates select='Form/Prop/PropList/Item'/>` does nothing when you are in the context of `Prop`. You want to select the items that are descendants of the current `Prop`, i.e. use a relative path in the form of `select='PropList/Item'`

Answer (score 1):

The output that you show us requires pivoting the table. A simpler approach would display the table in its existing orientation:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/Form">
    <html>
        <head><title>Sample Form</title></head>
        <body>
            <table border="1">
                <xsl:apply-templates select='Prop'/>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Prop">
    <tr>
        <th><xsl:value-of select="@title"/></th>
        <xsl:apply-templates select='PropList/Item'/>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item">
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@value"/></td>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result (rendered)**

[image]

---

### Edit

As I said, if you want to change the orientation of the table, you must work harder at it:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/Form">
    <html>
        <head><title>Sample Form</title></head>
        <body>
            <table border="1">
                <!-- header -->
                <xsl:for-each select="Prop">
                    <th><xsl:value-of select="@title"/></th>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <!-- body -->
                <xsl:for-each select="Prop[1]/PropList/Item">
                    <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()"/>
                    <tr>
                        <xsl:for-each select="/Form/Prop/PropList">
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="Item[$i]/@value"/></td>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result (rendered)**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the example. However, the header needs to be up to and to display each name, id, and code in a new row. I have updated the above example code to get the first column to display horizontally in row format, but unable to figure out how to make it call the next row(s).
Please see my example that I have added to the original post.

Comment: @J.Maxwell I don't see how the addition to your original post helps here: you either want to display the table as given (my original answer) or you want to pivot it (i.e. transpose rows to columns and vice versa), as shown in the edit to my answer.

Comment: @J.Maxwell Is this question not answered?